# Podman 1.6 bind mount creation issue

Tags: podman, buildah, rootless

I have updated to podman 1.6.4 on Centos 8. I'm trying to run the container:

```
$ podman run -ti -e DISPLAY --rm --security-opt=label=disable 
-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v /dev/dri:/dev/dri 
-v /run/media:/media:ro,slave 
--net=slirp4netns localhost/testcon_1
```

This yields

```
Error: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: 
container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: 
mounting \\\"/run/media\\\" to rootfs \\\"/home/pk/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/59ad384cd8074ba0459b2557b3d4d3a548bc6712418d4f4cd5e5e5d50acbe034/merged\\\" 
at \\\"/home/pk/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/59ad384cd8074ba0459b2557b3d4d3a548bc6712418d4f4cd5e5e5d50acbe034/merged/media\\\" 
caused \\\"operation not permitted\\\"\"": OCI runtime permission denied error
```

--log-level debug: https://pastebin.com/NZymQw6P

What's new in podman 1.6? Downgrade to 1.4.2 solved the problem.

Comment: This is strange, the command looks fine. Please open a bugzilla and we could look at it there.

Comment: I have similar problem with podman 1.8.2 on Ubuntu 19.10

    podman run --pull=never --rm -it --privileged -v $HOME:/media:ro centos:7.7.1908 /bin/bash

If I change :ro to :rw then it works. Also the above works on Fedora 31 podman 1.8.2

I think w/ older podman (but newer than 1.6) this used to work on Ubuntu too. Also mounting $HOME:$HOME:ro and /media:/media:ro works